# Lightstreamer Eventhandler in Win Forms

Tags: c#, winforms, lightstreamer

My question may sound very stupid (eventually it is^^) but I try to get an Lightstreamer stream in a WinForm Project. Client, Listener etc is successfully build.

```
IgStreamingApiClient R2D2 = new IgStreamingApiClient(_authenticationResponse);
CustomClientListener Dax = new CustomClientListener();
MarketListener DaxMarkt = new MarketListener();
```

My question is, in which part of the code do I run the stream, because I can't fetch any data.

```
List<string> Markets = new List<string>();
Markets.Add("IX.D.DAX.IFMM.IP");
R2D2.Connect(Dax);
R2D2.SubscribeToMarketUpdates(DaxMarkt, Markets);
```

Should I do a `while(sendData=true)`? Is there any magical Databinding? I have no clue where to get the item updates, maybe some of you could give me a hint.

Answer (score 0):

You should leverage the proper callback of the listener you used to subscribe (DaxMarkt).
Indeed, I expect that the MarketListener is a custom implementation of the [SubscriptionListener](https://sdk.lightstreamer.com/ls-dotnetstandard-client/5.1.1/api/api/com.lightstreamer.client.SubscriptionListener.html) interface; with the method [onItemUpdate](https://sdk.lightstreamer.com/ls-dotnetstandard-client/5.1.1/api/api/com.lightstreamer.client.SubscriptionListener.html#com_lightstreamer_client_SubscriptionListener_onItemUpdate_com_lightstreamer_client_ItemUpdate_) (or something similar) set up to receive updates in real time from the market.

Comment: Yes Sir, thats correct. But my Problem is, i don´t know how to connect wiht the Method onItemUpdate. I want the Streamdata in a label, but i´ve no clue how to connect the Marketlistener to the Winform.